# How to bind a Boolean column to a toggle button in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview, dataset

I have a typed `DataSet` with a single table named `Offset`.

[image: The Offset table]

`Hours` and `Minutes` are integers, and `IsNegative` is a `Boolean.` I want to bind a `DataGridView` to this table, and I want the `IsNegative` cell to look like a button whose label flips between '+' and '-' every time I click it.  By default, dragging the table from the Data Sources window onto the designer surface generates a [DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcheckboxcolumn%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for `IsNegative,` like so:

[image: DGV generated by dragging Offset]

An ordinary [CheckBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Properties) has the [Appearance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.appearance(v=vs.110).aspx) property, which can be set to `Button` to make it look like a toggle button, but a [DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcheckboxcolumn%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) doesn't seem to have an equivalent property; so I want to use a [DataGridViewButtonColumn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewbuttoncolumn%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) instead.  My question is how to bind it to my DataSet.  Which events do I need to handle and how do I know which row to change in the DataTable?  Do I have to use properties like [RowIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcelleventargs.rowindex(v=vs.110).aspx) or is there a more reliable way?

Comment: See if [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewbuttoncell(v=vs.110).aspx) helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can bind the column to a [`DataGridViewButtonColumn`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewbuttoncolumn.aspx). Then use the following events to satisfy the requirement:

- [`CellContentClick`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellcontentclick.aspx): to toggle the value.
- [`CellFormatting`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting.aspx): to show `-` instead of `true` and `+` instead of `false`

[image]

**Example**

Drop a `DataGridView` on the form and paste the following code for your form and run it:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("C1", typeof(bool)).DefaultValue = true;
    dt.Columns.Add("C2", typeof(string));
    dt.Rows.Add(true, "something");
    dt.Rows.Add(false, "something else");
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewButtonColumn()
    { DataPropertyName = "C1", Name = "C1", HeaderText = "C1" });
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    { DataPropertyName = "C2", Name = "C2", HeaderText = "C2" });
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    dataGridView1.CellFormatting += dgv_CellFormatting;
    dataGridView1.CellContentClick += dgv_CellContentClick;
}
private void dgv_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex < 0 || e.ColumnIndex != 0)
        return;
    var value = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value;
    if (value != null && value != DBNull.Value)
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = !(bool)value;
}

private void dgv_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex < 0 || e.ColumnIndex != 0)
        return;
    var value = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value;
    if (value != null && value != DBNull.Value)
        e.Value = (bool)value ? "-" : "+";
}
```

**Note**

To change the column type, it's enough to edit columns (using `Columns` property or by opening the smart tags panel and choosing 'edit columns'). Then in the column editor dialog, choose the check-box column and in the property grid, change its `ColumnType` to `DataGridViewButtonColumn`.